# Conversão de date javascript para sqlserver

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou tentando salvar um campo do tipo data no banco SQLSERVER, porém ele não insere, está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Seqüência não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.

```html
DateTime dat = DateTime.ParseExact(txtVencimentoC.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
cadastrocontasreceber.Vencimento = dat;
```

Tentei dessa forma, e de outras várias, porém todas me retornam o erro.
Como estou fazendo a soma de datas pelo javascript, o campo fica deste formato "Sun Nov 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)" 
Como posso fazer para formatá-lo para DateTime no SqlServer, ou como posso configurar dentro do javascript passando para o txtVencimentoC já formatado? Pois todas as formas me retornam o mesmo erro. Agradeço.

Comment: Não sei se irá funcionar, mas tente converter esta data para timestamp e aí sim mandar para o sql. Veja aqui como gerar o timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei este [link](http://www.guj.com.br/t/data-e-hora-javascript/57818/3) como referência. 
Ficou desta forma no código:

```js
document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = data.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```